# access database relationship between student and course. while keeping history of all previous course fee

Tags: database, ms-access

i want to keep all the record of student and course but after certain period of time if price of course changes then it should not affect previous record of student who have enrolled in different course fee... here is my database design please suggest me that my design is correct or not.

```
student
------------
id(pk),
name,
address,
email,

course
----------
id(pk),
name,
duration,
details,

course_fee
-----------
course_fee_id(pk),
course_id(fk),
course_fee,
valid_from,

student_course
--------------
student_course_id(pk),
student_id(fk),
course_fee_id(fk),
discount,
details,
```

### relationship

```
student.id-> student_course.student_id

course.id -> course_fee.course_id

course_fee.course_fee_id-> student_course.course_fee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy just make sure that in your relationship window you don't put referential integrity for the following relationship `course_fee.course_fee_id-> student_course.course_fee_i` that way data already entered will remain the same.

I would also suggest that you put some sort of date/time stamp field on your student_course table. :)

Comment: i dont understand if i dont put referential integrity 
for the following relationship then, incorrect
 data may be entered in student_course table example:

here is the link to that image please suggest me .

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIgqugOah3-bkdOVFpxVlpjZXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well I assume that you'll be using a form to enter the information so you just have to set the properties for that field's `Limit to List` to `Yes`

Comment: thanks .. then what the design should be if i want to put correct information in table level

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don't have users enter data directly into table level. as you said "incorrect data may be entered in student_course..." The only thing you need to do at table level is to have `student_course.course_fee_id` field set to lookup data from `course_fee.course_fee_id`